# I seem to have two desktops running concurrently as well as over the top of each other

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop

hope to god someone has seen this and knows wtf is going on :)

I hardly ever log directly into the machine and will generally just use X2GO to connect to it remotely.
I have not requested to install any new packages recently (other than the updates that pop up from time to time).

Today all of a sudden X2GO stopped working and the connection times out so I went to log into the machine directly and noticed that it seems to have two desktop environments running at the same time - not different sessions or anything - one running over the top of the other, you can see two different login screens depending where you put the mouse and once you have logged in it will give you two different mouse pointers.
You can interact with both desktops at the same time by "Choosing" which mouse pointer you want to follow/use (they are about 5cm apart on a 50" tv).

No idea how it has got like this nor how to get it back to normal. so any suggestions at this stage would be swell :)
If it's more of a to hard basket - that's fine I'll just reinstall.

many thanks in advance!

Tory

Comment: looks like reinstall it is...